# Can't get for loop to iterate enough times for my program to work

Tags: go

I'm trying to do some exercise our professor gave us to prepare for the exam, but I'm stuck on a pretty annoying problem.
The exercise require two inputs, n and d, and the program has to find the smallest number removing d decimals from the number n. The problem lies around line 40 or 41, because I don't know how to get enough loops to try out every possibily. As for now, the program is limited and won't work properly with most of the inputs.

**Example input:** 32751960 3
**Expected output:** 21960 (which is the smallest number we can get by removing 3 decimals from the first number)
**What I get:** 31960

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "math"
)

var (
    input string
    n, d, max int
    num, dec string
    in []int
)

func main (){
    getInput()
    max = n
    fmt.Println("Variables: ", n, d)

    //Check
    if d>len(num){
        fmt.Println(math.NaN())
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    //The problematic cicle
    for i:=d; i<=len(num); i++{ //On line 40 or 41 lies the problem: I don't get enough loops to check every possible combination,
                                //and at the same time i have to limit the i var to not exceed the slice boundaries
        temp := num[:i-d] + num[i:] 
        if temp == ""{ //To avoid blank strings
            continue
        }
        itemp, _ := strconv.Atoi(temp)
        fmt.Println(itemp)
        if itemp < max {
            max = itemp
        }

    }
    fmt.Println("Best number:",max)
}

func getInput(){
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    if scanner.Scan(){
        input = scanner.Text()
    }
    for _, s := range strings.Fields(input){
        i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        in = append(in, i) //
    }
    n = in[0] //main number
    d = in[1] //decimals to remove
    num = strconv.Itoa(n)
    dec = strconv.Itoa(d) 
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting at `i:=d` instead of `i:=0`? And it your `max` variable actually for holding the *minimum* value found, why is it called `max`, am I missing something? Also it appears your logic only allows for removing `d` *contiguous* digits, but from the description it seems like the answer you're looking for requires removing *any* `d` digits, is that right?

Comment: this is a recursion problem, no?   I would expect to see some recursive calling within your solution.

Comment: If I parsed the question correctly, what you're after is called "Cartesian product": the exhaustive search for any `d` is performed by `d` nested loops, each of which, on each iteration, removes a digit (in any order, say, from left to right) and calls the remaining loops on what it ended up with. Say, with `n = 1234` and `d = 2`, the outermost loop would call the inner loop with the inputs `234`, `134`, `124` and `123`, and the inner loop would test, e.g., `34`, `24` and `23` for the 1st input from the outer loop, and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question which has nothing to do with Go.

Comment: @Adrian if i use i:=0 it gives me a slice bounds out of range error. The "max" variable was called so because in the beginning i read that I had to look for the biggest number, so It was a mistake of mine. I can remove any digit in any position, but I can't move the numbers themselves

Comment: @kostix I think I understood, thank you. Basically I call the funcion d times and, everytime it is called, I remove one digit. I'm going to sleep right now but tomorrow I'm going to try it, thanks

Comment: @PandaSekh: remove `d` not contiguous digits then find smallest number. I recommend one loop for `d` digits `for i := 0; i < d; i++ {` and another loop for finding the `k` position to remove `for j := 0; j < k; j++ {`.

Comment: @A.R thanks for your answer, I'm going to try it asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need think about algorithm first.
And the digits to remove do not appear to be contiguous:
Here `temp := num[:i-d] + num[i:]` you are trying to remove 3 adjacent digits (for `d=3`) and you should try to remove also not adjacent digits.
Tip:
Remove one digit at a time (`k`): `n = n[:k] + n[k+1:]`

---

1. First for learning purpose, I recommend you to try the Brute-force method:   Generate all possible states and find the smallest number among them all.

---

2. For smallest number left digit is smaller than right side digit.
   Remove `d` not contiguous digits then find smallest number. I recommend one loop for `d` digits:
   `for i := 0; i < d; i++ {`
   and another loop for finding the `k` position to remove:
   `for j := 0; j < k; j++ {`.

Like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Djdv8cxcEei) and [this](https://play.golang.org/p/W-LrR009K0g):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    n := "32751960"
    d := 3
    // fmt.Scan(&n, &d)
    for i := 0; i < d; i++ {
        k := len(n) - 1
        for j := 0; j < k; j++ {
            if n[j] > n[j+1] {
                k = j
                break
            }
        }
        n = n[:k] + n[k+1:]
    }
    fmt.Println(n) // 21960
}
```

---

3. Using 1 loop, like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/d2OZ-vREgdg):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    n := "322311"
    d := 3
    // fmt.Scan(&n, &d)
    for j := 0; j < len(n)-1; j++ {
        if n[j] > n[j+1] {
            n = n[:j] + n[j+1:]
            j = -1
            d--
            if d <= 0 {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    n = n[:len(n)-d]
    fmt.Println(n) // 211
}
```

Comment: the digits to remove do not appear to be contiguous, based on the input/output provided: **3**2**75**1960 -> `21960`

Comment: As @colminator pointed out, I can remove digits from any position. My code was wrong from the concept itself

Comment: The one with only one loops doesn't work with certain inputs, while the first one always works. Thanks!

Comment: @PandaSekh: You're welcome. Corrected One loop version to start a loop from the beginning for each digit. so you may check it again.